# GCP: load balancer rewrite path

Tags: google-cloud-platform, network-programming, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I'm setting up traffic management for a global external HTTP(S) load balancers. I have two backend Cloud Run services, `serverless-lb-www-service` and `serverless-lb-api-service`, that I want to serve from the same IP/domain.

I want to configure them like this:

`example.com` -> `serverless-lb-www-service`

`example.com/api` -> `serverless-lb-api-service`

I can use the simple routing rules to serve traffic *semi-expected*:

| path | backend |
| --- | --- |
| /* | serverless-lb-www-service |
| /api | serverless-lb-api-service |
| /api/* | serverless-lb-api-service |

However, I'm running into an issue where I try to access an endpoint that is not the root API end, like `example.com/api/test`. I'm always seeing the response I would expect from `example.com/api`.

I believe it has something to do with my API (running express.js) receiving the path `/api` when it is instead expecting to serve that route from there just `/test`. I think I might need to set up a rewrite to remove `/api` when it hits the API

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

**update**

I can confirm that the requests as logged in the API are all prefixed with `/api`. I can solve my issue by changing all API route handlers to expect the `/api` prefix in production environment. However I would still rather do this via a path rewrite so application code is the same in all environments

Comment: Based from the details that you have provided, does the /api and /api/* have the same backend?

Comment: @mr.vin yes it does. I could most likely remove `/api` all together

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the host and path rules. You can follow the steps through this [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-load-balancing-go-beyond-your-own-project-adfa1c8b001d#:%7E:text=And%20hit%20Create-,Customize%20the%20host%20and%20path%20rules,This%20customization%20can%20be%20complex%20here.%20But%20here%20my%20requirement%3A,-I%20want%20to). It is also using Cloud Run services and might help you with the rewrite path issues.

Note: Just scroll all the way down if the link will not redirect and show the "Customize the host and path rules" steps.